# VScode Mac - none of my extensions are loading

Tags: visual-studio-code

I opened VSCode yesterday and none of my extensions are loading. Instead there's just a blue clock symbol ion the bottom corner. I'm trying to use the LaTeX workshop extension and the SSH client but none of the extensions will load.

I tried fully reinstalling VSCode but had no success.

Operating System: MacOS 12.6.6
Visual Studio Code Version: 1.79.1
LaTeX Workshop Version: v9.11.4
TeX Distribution Version: TeX Live 2020

The document and code should compile with no problems. I tried fully purging all software related to vscode but got no luck. I'm not sure how to fix the problem.

Ram extension bisect and got nowhere

No antivirus and the machine is brand new

EDIT: for those curious I haven't found a full fix but rolling back to last month's version worked.

Comment: It’s blank no output

Comment: It says nothing and none of my extensions are loading

Comment: No none. The machine is brand new

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: Try running the `Extension Bisect` command to see if one of your extensions is causing the problem.

Comment: How do I do that? I’ve tried reinstalling again

Comment: It's a command in the Command Palette.

Comment: Nope no problems

Answer (score -1):

In VSCode, press F1. Type in the search: "user settings." Next, in the search for settings, type "proxy." In the User - > Application - > Proxy - Find the item "Http: Proxy Support (use the proxy support for extensions)." And then turn on the "fallback."

Comment: Hmm that didn’t seem to work :(

Comment: Try to reset the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. Identify the files that export this variable at startup and comment on them. Are there any error message in the Console of the Developer Tools (Help>Toggle Developer Tools)?